# Cannot instantiate and call method on this instance oneliner

Tags: java

Would anyone explain me why I can't write something like this:

```
public class TestService {
     new myService().move();
}
```

Comment: You can offcourse write this in method

Comment: you can write, but just at the right place. Move that code inside some method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this should be inside a method and not in the middle of nowhere in the class. Example:

```
public class TestService {

   public void myCoolMethod() {
       new myService().move();
   }

}
```

Or in a (non-static) initializer:

```
public class TestService {

   {
       new myService().move();
   }

}
```

Comment: One question when the non-static block will be executed ??

Comment: @Youngistan See [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) for good explanation.

Comment: Thanks but i have one concern compiler copies non-static block 'new myService().move()' to default constructor so this may rise to stack over flow  exception

Comment: Why so you think `StackOverflowException` will be thrown?

Comment: so sorry @Maroun Maroun i thought method of same class is called.

Answer (score 3):

Write this line in any method or static block:

```
static {
    new myService().move();
}
```

or

```
public void move() {
    new myService().move();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A static code block or a method body will allow you to execute that statement:

```
public class TestService {
  static
  {
    new myService().move();
  }
}
```